# OpenNN Release library not found during make?

Tags: c++, opennn

First, if this is not a good place to ask this/put this please let me know

so I have been trying to get this to work for.... a week or two now, but to no avail, and getting the same error every single time and I no longer know what to do
heres what I get every single time I try to run the command make after running cmake -DCMAKE_TYPE_BUILD=Release .

[image: I get this every time I try to run make with this, no matter what I do]

any help would be appreciated as I want this to work(I have tried litterally now about 23 different libraries for C++ neural networks that support lstm and/or CNN's, and only 1 has worked but it doesnt support either of those)
Thanks!

Comment: This seems more like a CMake question than a c++ question. Because of that, it would be helpful if you could provide a minimal cmake file. What already strikes me as odd, though is that `-l` params are usually followed by a library identifier (for example `opennn`) and not a path as you have it. The paths a linker looks for those libraries can be passed with -L

Comment: It appears that airfoil_self_noise is trying to link with opennn library and may this is not built yet

Comment: Were you able to figure out the solution to this? I am having a similar issue...